# How to show image using folder path from database

Tags: php, mysql, image, forms

I save image in a folder. The name of the image is saved in database . But I want to show image using this code .My code is given bellow

```
                                <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
                                include'connect.php';
                                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM descriptionoftree WHERE id = $_GET[id]");
                                $update = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

                            ?>
                 <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Image</label>
                        <?php echo"<img  alt='Responsive   image' border=\"0\" src=\"image".$update['image']."\" width=\"150\" alt=\"image\" height=\"120\">";
```

?>
                               
I have a form and i want to show image in this form using image path from the database.

but in this form not show the image !

Comment: undefined index means the `id` field is  not available in the database table.

Comment: but i have an field!

Comment: Show your all source code.

Comment: var_dump() or print() your result and look for `id` value.

Comment: do yourself a big favour and learn to format your code

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```html
 <a href="?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Update</a>
```